# refreshing spring boot properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a spring integration web application that imports a bunch of properties file like so:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
```

Now I am converting it to a spring boot application and I am importing the the properties in using the @PropertySource in the config class.  I am also looking at the spring cloud config server for a future state project.  So my question is this, all of the beans that need to be refreshed when the properties file changes need @RefreshScope but there is no equivalent attribute in the xml at this point that I am aware of.  I thought I could use scope="refresh" the application throw an error saying "refresh" is not a valid scope.  So how do I manage refreshing the xml defined beans when the properties file changes.

I'm thinking I could try and capture the event and then do a context.refresh(); but is their a better way to do this that is already built into spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register a custom `Scope` you need to declare a bean definition. Spring Cloud Config does that for you if you use `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. If you don't then you need to create it manually (XML or not XML). E.g.

```
@Bean
public static RefreshScope refreshScope() {
    return new RefreshScope();
}
```

(link: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/1.0.0.M2/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.java#L63)