# Better way to update Spring Boot properties while app is running

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, properties

So far, I have seen methods to update a Spring boot application, by changing the property file itself, then reloading the file, or by using `@RefreshScope` annotation, or by Spring Cloud Config.

I was not able to find anything straight forward (something like `getEnvironment().updateProperty(key, value)` ).

Is there such a way to do that?

For example, I need to change the logging type of my application, to show the SQL;
My `application.properties` file contains this line: `spring.jpa.show-sql=false`.

But what if I want to set this to `true` while the application is running, through a REST call?

Can you suggest a simpler way to do this? And/Or show examples of how you would do it yourself, for this specific property?

EDIT: The changes do not need to be reflected in the `application.properties` file. So when the application is restarted, it would use the properties that were initially set in the `application.properties` file.

Comment: There isn't. Properties are applied at load-time... Changing them requires a restart or recreation of beans (hence the `@RefreshScope`). You might be able to use JMX to change some properties in a running application but this won't be reflected in your `application.properties`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, the properties do not need to be reflected in the properties file. They just need to be applied to the current running instance.

Comment: You can with Spring-Boot Cloud. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717187/refreshing-spring-boot-properties#26717273

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refreshing spring boot properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717187/refreshing-spring-boot-properties)

Comment: @gtonic I would like to see, if possible, specific examples for the property described in my post, which keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: I've done this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287771/how-to-reload-a-value-property-from-application-properties-in-spring/40288822#40288822)

Comment: @Essex Boy This still requires changing the the application.properties file, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you want to change a property you're going to have to tell it what the new property is somehow!!

Comment: As far as I know, you can set properties programatically. So it would require setting/resetting that property programatically, then refreshing the application scope.

Comment: This answer exactly what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648630/39998

Comment: I would go with Consul KV, instead of any custom implementation, as the third party would have been thoroughly tested and provide more features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kubernetes env](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) like below:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
      value: "prod"
```

If not use kubernetes, you can use database(I prefer NoSql for this solution) to changing your properties.
write `schedule` for getting data from your database and update your properties